# Force acting on an object traveling upwards (ignoring air resistance)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, acceleration, weight

Could someone please help explain to me which formula should be used for a question like this...

A ball with the mass of 166.1 g is thrown vertically upwards with an initial velocity of 18.5 m/s. It is allowed to fall back to its original position. Ignoring air resistance, calculate the force acting on the ball during its upward movement.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force acting on the ball=mg=1.661N for the entire upward and downward motion.

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to physics. Could you please explain how you got to that answer? Thank you

Comment: The only force(external) acting on the ball is the gravitation force, which is an attractive force acting towards the centre of the Earth here. The gravitation force is given by F=GmMe/r^2. Where Me is mass of the Earth and m is mass of body. r is distance of body from centre of Earth. For small heights above the Earth, r~R(radius of Earth). GMe/R^2 is a constant value, called acceleration due to gravity (g) value is ~ 9.8m/s^2. It may be taken as 10m/s^2 for ease of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Body will only experience a vertical downward force that is mg =1.661N